# Can I use any bluetooth printer with Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, printing, windows-phone-8, bluetooth

I am developing an application where I have to print information because of that I am using a AP1300 this is a bluetooth printer but nothing happens. Do I need an specific kind of printer for doing so,thanks for your answers.

Comment: You may be better off asking this question on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Such printer needs Drivers.  And as you can see on the website, WP8 is not (yet?) supported.

Comment: I understand, could you please give me a sugestion, I would like to get one that works for windows phone.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it requires a fair amount of low-level RS232/Serial code and might not work with your specific printer. See [Can I print with windows phone 8 using Bluetooth to a portable printer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162889/can-i-print-with-windows-phone-8-using-bluetooth-to-a-portable-printer) for a few suggestions and links.

First obstacle is whether your phone can pair with the printer. If you can't, the printer uses a BT profile not supported by your phone. If it can you might be able to write code against it, provided the pairing is using a profile you can write code against, and you can figure out the correct commands required to send to the printer (look up developer doc for the printer if available).

Lastly only apps that you write will work (or if someone else wrote an app for your printer). You won't find any support for any of the built-in apps, so no printing of emails, word documents etc.